# C++: handling multiple input sources, outputability and exception flags, and timers from multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, select, event-handling

I've been programming single-threaded event-driven apps for 30 years.

Generally speaking, this is done by 1) setting all IO to be non-blocking, then 2) writing a wrapper around `select()`, `poll()` or similar that maintains a timer event queue and arrays of file descriptors to be monitored for readability, writability, and exceptions.  Inter alia, the X Windows Toolkit Intrinsics (Xt) and the XView library provide such wrappers, as does Reuters RTR and several other sources.

The result is a single-threaded app that nonetheless can monitor an arbitrary number of file handles (such as TCP sessions, user events from a windowing environment, etc.) along with large set of timers.  If a socket becomes readable (that is, more data is present) it is read.  If it becomes writable (that is, the write cache is fully or partially cleared) more data can be written, and so on.

Now I'm writing the same general type of software in a multi-thread environment.

Clearly one approach is to make ALL I/O blocking, and devote separate threads to reading and writing each TCP connection.  Likewise threads could be asleep until woken up by timers (I presume possible but how?).  However the programmer workload of setting up all these threads and assuring they're accessing common variables with locks, or atomic operations that will work in all situations, seems to be worse than the old-school approach.

The other extreme is to maintain the single-select, which might be something of a bottleneck but would be most familiar to me and allow the most reuse of old code.  Here's an example of why it simply can'tbe used as is in a multi-threaded world, however.  Say I wanted a timer to go off in 1 second, but `select()` is blocking for 2 seconds for its next timer event, and there's no other file activity that would otherwise cause `select()` to return.  My 1-second timer would go  off at *earliest* in 2 seconds, and that's if I record the time-of-day that I got the request at.  (If I naively obeyed the 1-second callback time when I processed the message, it'd instead go off 3 seconds later instead of the 1 requested.)

As a workaround, I can create a pipe and register one end to be monitored for incoming data with `select()` just like any file descriptor.  Threads other than the main thread simply write their request to register or remove a timer or input source into the pipe.  That incoming data wakes up select() and the main thread can then (almost) immediately add it to its timer queue, or add/remove the file descriptor from its array of those being monitored, etc.

This also has some thorny issues, as registering a timer for instance becoming asynchronous.  Should you pass in a reference to an object that wants a timer, then later want to delete this object before the timer goes off, you don't know if you're safe to free it as the timer might not be registered yet, and the de-registration would likewise be asynchronous.  Let's say I have acceptable solutions for all that (such as simply not deleting such objects).

But I'm sure there's some standard approaches used in between these two extremes.  What might they be?  Maybe as simple as having a `select()`-based top loop for each thread that needs timers or I/O events?